# filtering via sql from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I am a newbie in SQL and I have a few sql tables which look like so:

```
customers (customer_id, name,email), 
orders (order_id, customer_id, order_date, total_amount), 
order_items (order_id, product_id, amount) and 
products (product_id, name, price)
```

Id like to get the names of all customers who have placed at least one order
with a total amount greater than $100 in the last 30 days, ordered by total amount
in descending order.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ORDERS >100
```

I am not sure this is correct since it also does not take the last 30 days into account.

How do I construct such a query in raw SQL?

Comment: Learn how to use `JOIN`.

Comment: Working with dates would vary by DBMS. Look up how to query date difference for your type of dbms. You should also add that DBMS to your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM CUSTOMERS 
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON ORDERS.customer_id = CUSTOMERS.customer_id
WHERE ORDERS.total_amount > 100
  AND ( CURRENT_DATE - ORDERS.order_date ) <= 30
```

The `CURRENT DATE - ORDERS.order_date` is different in different RDBMS's.

- The given example works in PostgreSQL
- In MySQL you will have to use: [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)
- In MSSQL it's: [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)